# How to create relationships during event registration

Tags: civievent, relationships, participants

I would need to create **relationships** between participants when **registering for an event** in the CiviCRM online registration form.

I have seen there is an **CiviCRM extension** that promises to do that:

https://civicrm.org/blog/sarahgladstone/new-extension-creating-relationships-durring-event-registration

but it seems it is not fully developed yet.

I have tried to use Caldera Forms for the event registration, as the CMS is WordPress, but it can't process payments as this plugin is no longer maintained and I can't get a license for the integration of the Payment processors with Caldera Forms.

Is there any **CiviCRM extension** that allows to **create relationships between participants** to an event?

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an extension, but you can write an extension add a relation between Additional participant and Primary participant

Answer (score 1):

[CiviRules](https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/) perhaps? Haven't tested it personally, however  it has "Participant is added" trigger and "Add Relationship" Action so maybe it can do.

Comment: Not currently, as the Add Relationship action only lets you specify a fixed contact, not the registered by contact or something like that. So that Action would have to be expanded to allow something like this.

Answer (score 1):

The ["Group Event Participant Registration" extension](https://github.com/twomice/com.joineryhq.groupreg) does create relationships among contacts in in a multi-participant registration.

(I'm the author. The extension has been in production use for a couple of years by a client, but I've never bothered to promote it or list it on civicrm.org.)

The basic intent is to allow one person (who may not even be attending) to register others in their family or workplace. From the readme:

> - Allows registering user to indicate whether they will attend the event or not.
> - Provides list of related contacts as optional pre-filled additional participants.
> - Related contacts may be related directly to the registering user, or (optionally) through a mutually related organization.
> - Records all additional participants as related to user, with relationship type selected by user.
>
> ...
> See beta demo video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2zd3bENs0Ow&t=722s

Comment: Many thanks for facilitating this extension for the benefit of all. I have installed it, but it is not working as described on the video. I downloaded it from https://github.com/twomice/com.joineryhq.groupreg/archive/master.zip. Is that the last version?

Comment: What I am finding is that when the additional participant is selected, the fields "First Name" and "Last Name" are not pre-filled automatically. And as they are locked, it is not possible to introduce their value.

Comment: Also the "First Name", "Last Name" and "Email" fields (fields contained in the Event Profile for the Online Registration) only appear when a contact is selected and the button "Continue" is clicked.

Comment: I have also found that the Participant Role for the Primary Participant not attending is not the one configured in the Event Configuration (Non-attending registrant).

Comment: You've got the right URL, Christina P. Would you mind filing an issue (or multiple issues) at https://github.com/twomice/com.joineryhq.groupreg/issues ? That will be a better place to get detailed help than in these comments.